# FPGAs: Pins and their polarities

Tags: fpga

After mucking about with the FPGA, I became had a near heart attack while assigning pins.

There are any number of pins on an FPGA, and some IDEs are helpful and give you access to the package information ranging from what pins there are, what IO bank they are a part of and what the **polarity** is. After extensively digging around on the manufacturer's and competitors' websites, reading through tutorials, information sheets, guides etc. I was still none the wiser. After some more mucking about, I *think* I understand what this means, but hope someone can clarify this for me and others like myself who might be just as confused.

**On Polarity:**
Does the **polarity** indicate in what state the input must be in (IE: True or complementary)? or does it indicate the **polarity** that the input is received in?

Does this mean that an additional resources will be required by the FPGA to convert the input/output to the desired state? Or does this mean that I have the inputs coming in at the correct polarity for the FPGA to register the inputs correctly?

Otherwise, I am completely confused by the concept of **polarity** as it relates to the IO on an FPGA. Is this something I really need to be concerned about?

**On IO banks:**
are IO banks grouped according to which part of the FPGA they link into? If this is the case, I'd assume that IO Banks that are grouped together operate faster together. Is the consequence of distributing inputs to the FPGA across disparate IOs result in the consumption of resources and sub-optimal performance, or is this a big problem that prevents proper operation?

I'm not having much luck on finding any literature that explains this. The time I spent in a class in 2014 was helpful for breaking the ice with programming FPGAs but the course had many deficiencies and discrepancies for learning goals, and there wasn't much else available. I'm hoping this question will help others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Some IO pins support differential signals like LVDS. Therefor some pins are "paired" to support this kind of signalling, each one having either positive or negative polarity. In this case it is not irrelevant which signal (positive or negative wire of a differential pair) is connected to which pin. However you can often just logically invert the signal inside the FPGA if you got it wrong, at least if you have access to the corresponding HDL code.
For single ended inputs there is no conecpt of polarity, it's up to your design logic to define if a pin should behave high active or low active.
Regarding IO banks, they just group together a number of pins, and yes usually each side of an FPGA gets its own bank, but sometimes there are more (or less) banks available. The most important concept of banks is probably that each bank gets its own supply voltage, which limits the number of logic standards that can be used on a bank, e.g. you can't use pins with LVCMOS33 and LVCMOS18 at the same time on the same bank.
From a timing perspective it is also important to keep related pins on the same bank. This is because many FPGAs offer special IO clocking networks which can distribute clocks within a bank. This improves timing and can often save you a global clock buffer.